# pass data to reminder.blade file

Tags: php, laravel, password-recovery

I'm making a password reset with laravel. What I need is to pass the name of the user in the email but I can't access to the file reminder.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Bonjour "I need to put the user firstname here !!"</h2>
        <div>
            <h5>Nous avons bien recu votre demande de réinitialisation de mot de passe 
                pour l'access au Back office Happy Road</h5>
            <h5>Pour redéfinir votre mot de passe, suivez ce lien:</h5>
            <h5> {{ URL::to('resetPassword', array($token)) }}.</h5>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this about [passing data to views](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views).

So you might want to do something like this in your Controller:

```
View::make('reminder')->withFirstname($first_name);
```

Then in your view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello {{ $first_name }}</h2>
        <div>
            <h5>Nous avons bien recu votre demande de réinitialisation de mot de passe 
                pour l'access au Back office Happy Road</h5>
            <h5>Pour redéfinir votre mot de passe, suivez ce lien:</h5>
            <h5> {{ URL::to('resetPassword', array($token)) }}.</h5>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a View Composer to do that for you:

```
View::composer('*', function($view)
{
    $view->with('current_user', Auth::user());
});
```

Then in your view

```
<h1>Bonjour "{{$current_user->first_name}}"

<h5>Nous avons bien recu votre demande de réinitialisation de mot de passe 
            pour l'access au Back office Happy Road</h5>
```

Composers share variables with all your views or the views you select, like:

```
View::composer('reminder', function($view)
{
    $view->with('current_user', Auth::user());
});
```

You can create a `composers.php` file and load it in your `app/start/global.php file`:

```
require app_path().'/composers.php';
```

Also, check the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers